# Who is this person on the cover of the Star Wars Radio Drama?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, character-identification

[image]

I don't remember this person being in the *film*, do we know who he is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Randy Martinez](https://randymartinez.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/art-focus-official-star-wars-a-new-hope-radio-drama-cd-cover/) (the picture's illustrator), the character on the far left is [Lord Tion](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tion_(Human)), a character who appears in the Radio Drama but not the film. Martinez goes on to say that he modelled the character **on himself**, which would explain why you don't recognise him.

Interestingly, Martinez is incorrect when he says that Tion hasn't been depicted before since he actually made [a brief appearance](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/b/bc/Tion%28Lord%29.JPG/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/360?cb=20130707042620) in the 2003 "Star Wars: Empire" series of comics before getting himself shot by Leia.

> ***As for that handsome devil on the left, that is none other than Lord
>   Tion.*** Lord who? I know, that’s what I tought too, at first, but Lord
>   Tion is a great character. Lord Tion is a high-ranking officer in the
>   Galactic Empire, and like all imperial swine, he is a plotting,
>   ambitious, scheming slime ball. He is arrogant, ruthless, and has
>   designs to marry Princess Leia. I was lucky enough to get assigned to
>   illustrate two key scenes that feature Lord Tion and Princess Liea. **I
>   really wanted to capture Lord Tions rotten expressions, so I modeled
>   Lord Tion after myself.** Wait, I’m not saying I’m rotten… let me
>   explain. I will often use models for action poses or different scenes
>   that I paint. My friend Michael Bender, for instance, modeled as all
>   my stormtroopers in the project.  For Lord Tion, I really wanted to
>   nail some subtle expressions and feelings. I knew exactly what I
>   wanted, so rather than get a model, I took pictures of myself for
>   reference. I took TONS of photos until I got the  expressions I wanted
>   just right, leaving me with some pretty funny outtakes. I honestly
>   never thought my depictions of Lord Tion would be more than the
>   Trading Cards, but when I got tapped to do the CD cover I got very
>   excited because it meant my face would be in official key art for Star
>   Wars. My face is now the official Star Wars personification of Lord
>   Tion… kinda cool!:)